How would you implement a map system like WoW?
I'm really struggling with a 'resonable' technical implementation of the map system used by the popular MMO World of Warcraft. Not really sure on a data structure format and how to save/store it in a SQL relational DB. I've come up with an idea below, but wondered if anyone had any better ways?
A brief summary of the map system used by World of Warcraft:

Loading up the map starts with a blank outline of a continent
Each continent has multiple 'zones', which are outlined, but blank
Selecting a 'zone' zooms into the zone, but it is initially blank
As the player explores the zone, certain areas within the zone will 'be discovered' and will be coloured and detailed in
Players need to explore the whole zone for it to be fully discovered and show a 'complete' map
Players can discover any area of the map in any order
Maps and areas are not rigid, they can be complex and different shapes and sizes

My current thinking:

Use a 2D tool to create the following 2D assets
The blank outline of a zone
Multiple transparent layers with a certain area 'coloured', which could be overlayed onto the blank outline
Assign an integer ID to each area layer
When a player discovers a zone
Attempt to find the correct corresponding layer and assigned 'integer'
Add this integer to an array corresponding to a zone
When a player logs off
save this array to a string, seperating the integers with a underscore
save this string to a seperate SQL table, using the character ID as a primary key
When a player logs on
load all rows using the character ID as a lookup
Load all of the integers sperating them out with the underscore
use the integers as a ID reference to the transparent layers to show as visible

Thoughts?

It is similar to fog of war for maps, just instead of a noise image for undiscovered area, you have a gray scale image (or similar)

I have some code/design review feedback. Your design would work for a single-player game (or even a small-scale multiplayer one with ~64 concurrent players), but it has a few problems that would start to show on the scale of an MMO.
The patches should be one-channel, not full images
Rather than separating the map out into a layer for each area, it would be better to have only two layers for the map - one which is completely filled in, and one which is completely unexplored. Then, have a patch for each area which is a single one-bit channel to indicate the shape of each area. The client can then composite all of the explored patches to get a composite shape of all the explored area.
In areas where the composite of patches is white, it would draw from the explored map. In areas where it is black, it would draw from the unexplored map.
This will let you apply border-effects - for example, by running a blur filter over the composite alpha channel before applying it to the map, you can make the explored areas "fade" to unexplored at the edges, while neither needing to pre-fade the edges of patches by hand nor making the map blurry.
It will also reduce the size of the map in memory. Images are not compressed in VRAM, so if your patches are all transparent layers over the whole map, that will take up as much space on the graphics card as if every layer was a complete copy of the map - even though most of those pixels are fully transparent on each layer.
 
Rely on existing systems
In an MMO, there will need to be another system responsible for persisting character data (such as their inventory, how much experience they have, their last known position, etc.) when the player logs in and out. Information about what areas the player has explored should be made part of this character data, not implemented as a standalone query that also runs at log-in.
These systems have lots of other concerns which you don't want to think about when you're writing your map, so, while writing the map, you should just assume that the character data system works correctly and just use it.
Your existing design assumes that the server will never crash and that database writes will never fail, for example. You'd want the mapping system to still work even under those conditions, but it shouldn't be the mapping system's responsibility to handle those conditions.
Don't store a set of integers as a string
Storing a set of integers as an underscore delimited string is one of the worst possible implementations, for several reasons.

It consumes extra memory/disk space, taking a minimum of 8-bits per decimal digit instead of 4-bits per hexadecimal digit in the computer's native representation.
It consumes extra compute at load time, since it has to be parsed.
It is not compatible with any off-the-shelf tools (such as JSON parsers).

Storing a large set of things (where the only relevant information is whether or not a given element is in the set) is something that an MMO will already need to do - for example, with quests, WoW has thousands of quests, and it needs to store whether or not each character completed all of them. Storing them as a string would take about 40kb per 1000 quests, and the entire string would need to be run through a parser on every log-in, and then it would somehow need to be sent to the player (and you really don't want to be sending an extra 40kb of data to every player on every log-in if you can help it). Storing it as a list of native integers is a little bit better, but still takes at least 16kb per 1000 quests.
Use a vector of bits instead
In this case, I would recommend storing it as a vector of bits. For example, if you have 128 distinct sub-regions, you could save a 128-bit number (as a number, in your server's native number format), where each bit in that number corresponds to the explored/unexplored status of a different area. If your numbers are too wide, you can save several (for example, a 256-bit number could be stored as 4 64-bit numbers).
This number can then be read directly into memory (and sent directly to the client) without the server needing to interpret it at all, saving on memory, compute, and bandwidth.
As with the character data, though, the map system should not define its own "vector of bits" data structure - likely, the character data system should already support such a thing, and the map system should just use it.

Tim this is absolutely amazing feedback, thanks very much! A few follow-up questions if I may:

Map Patches: Sounds absolutely great, I could imagine the end-result working in an Unreal Material, but struggling with how to store & feed in those patches, do you have any references I can follow up on?
Use existing systems: Yes totally agree & implied
Vector of Bits: Not really sure on this, do you mean a vector of integers? Is that a datatype in SQL?


@Subressor - I'm not familiar with Unreal Engine, so I can't give any advice specific to that tool. I'd be able to explain how to do it in Unity, though. For the vector of bits, I am using "vector" here in the C++ sense (basically an array). A 64-bit integer can be used to "pack" 64 booleans, by treating each bit of the integer as an independent 0-1 value. The keyword to look up for reference is "bit flags." I don't know if Unreal supports these natively, so you may have to go to the C++ layer to do this. (And if you're making an MMO in Unreal, get comfortable with the C++ layer)

Further thought: Regarding Unreal Materials - I think it would be best to post that as a separate question on this site. Questions about how to use Unreal Engine is something that lots of people here can help you with (just not me).
